# Python - Command Line Closes

Tags: python

I'm having a bit of fun with python creating classes and methods and stuff but I have one problem.

Say I have this code:

```
class Circle:
    def __init__(self, radius):
        self.radius = radius

    def increaseR(self):
        self.radius += 1
```

The code itself runs perfectly fine. But when I run the .py file, it runs it through the shell (I think that's what it's called), then it closes it. While I realize that this is completely normal to happen, I was wondering how I could keep it open so someone can toy around with the program and do stuff like:

```
c = Circle(1)
c.radius
c.increaseR
```

Basically play around with the class and get output from the shell. But it closes too fast, and I don't want to have to run it from my IDE every time (where the shell stays open).

Basically I want the shell to stay open and keep taking input from the user until you literally click the red x on the shell window.

Sorry if I sound dumb, I just started Python programmming.

Thank you!

Bella

Comment: you could do something super simple like adding something like `while True: exec(input('What would you like to do'))` in your main. if you want to do simpl e things like `print(c.radius)` and such. this is not a failsafe mode by any standard but if you just want to play around with your class this will work.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-i` option while opening your terminal. Just replace `your_file.py` with the file you wish to execute.

```
python -i your_file.py
```

Comment: I think I may have asked this wrong. When I double click the actual .py file, it runs it through a terminal like this: http://prntscr.com/8zfpie I don't actually open the terminal then run it from there

Comment: Go through this https://docs.python.org/2/faq/windows.html Make sure you know how to run fire-up python in the command line.

Answer (score 0):

you may need this:

```
$ python -i your_source.py
```

you can also use -c to excecute code as parameter like this:

```
$ python -c "print 3*2"
6
```